# Change Language of CodeIgniter calendar library

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime, internationalization, multilingual

I am trying to internationalize my site... so far I am able to translate everything except my dates and times.

I am trying to get the dates and times to display in French.

[image]

I have tried to use the `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'France');` before loading the calendar library, all to no avail.

I am using the default codeigniter calendar library.

EDIT: my calendar function

```
/**
 * generates an HTML calendar table
 * @param string   $year
 * @param string   $month
 * @param int|null $student_id
 */
public function generateCalendar($year, $month, $student_id = null)
{
    $params = [
        'show_next_prev' => false,
    ];

    $params['translated_month_names'] = [
        '01' => 'sfdgsdfg',
        '02' => 'vncvbm',
        '03' => 'vbbddg',
        '04' => 'xcvbbb',
        '05' => 'xfjyt',
        '06' => 'xfghxfgb',
        '07' => 'jhdcbxcvb',
        '08' => 'zgfbhxcvn',
        '09' => 'zrthxgb',
        '10' => 'zfgxcgnx',
        '11' => 'november',
        '12' => 'december'
    ];

    // loading the calendar and passing the params and data
    $this->load->library('calendar', $params, $month);
    return $this->$month->generate($year, $month);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you declare prefs ?

```
$prefs['translated_day_names'] = array('monday in your language', 'wtorek', 'środa', 'czwartek', 'piątek', 'sob', 'niedziela');
$prefs['translated_month_names'] = array('01' => 'january in your language', '02' => '...', '03' => '...', '04' => '...', '05' => '...', '06' => '...', '07' => '.', '08' => '.kk', '09' => 'yyy', '10' => 'yy', '11' => 'november in your language', '12' => 'december');
```

and then

```
$this->load->library('calendar', $prefs);
```

Comment: Okay I will try that, thanks never seen this before. Will get back to you and accept answer if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working and I cant seem to find information on 'translated_month_names' anywhere...  I updated my answer with my current calendar class.

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this pesky issue by changing the code in the core Calender class (system/libraries/Calendar.php). There's nothing in the docs which says anything about languages so i decided to tweak it on my own.

You may also choose to extend the base library and overwrite the two functions which I modified, however I did not do that because for some weird reason it can't find base classes (system/libraries/CI_Calendar) when I try to extend them as described in the docs. It will always return that it cannot find the CI_Calendar class in my setup, but that is a different matter.

In libraries/Calendar.php I made the following small changes, be aware that this is not the entire function code and you may need to tweak a bit to get the desired result (this was it for me):

**function get_month_name()**

```
$months = $this->CI->lang->line('translated_month_names');

    return ($months === FALSE)
        ? ucfirst(substr($month_names[$month], 4))
        : $months[$month];
```

When there is no case for "translated_month_names" in the loaded language files it will take the default which have been declared above.

**function get_day_names()**

```
$days = array();

    if($this->CI->lang->line('translated_day_names')){
        $days = $this->CI->lang->line('translated_day_names');
    }else{
        for ($i = 0, $c = count($day_names); $i < $c; $i++)
        {
        $days[] = ($this->CI->lang->line('cal_'.$day_names[$i]) === FALSE) ? ucfirst($day_names[$i]) : $this->CI->lang->line('cal_'.$day_names[$i]);
        }   
    }
```

This will ensure it will parse my language files if there is a line for it, else it will take the default (English). I Hope this may help some folks on this hellish library. Mine works great now using the default language class provided by CodeIgniter.

Comment: Yep, I am living with this bug for now... not the end of the world, but thanks for sharing your solution! I am probably going to move to some sort of javascript calendar eventually.

Answer (score 0):

You might not change the language with add some array in $perfs variable, but i have another way by changing the library file on :

C:\xampp\htdocs\CI FOLDER Name\system\libraries\calendar.php

```
$day_names = array('su', 'mo', 'tu', 'we', 'th', 'fr', 'sa');
```